# How to properly update a managed entity using data from a non-managed entity?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

## Context

My goal is to perform an update on a managed entity using data from an object of the same class, but non-managed by Doctrine.

This would be cool if it was possible to perform a "simple update", when replacing attributes, but in fact, if I clean an `ArrayCollection`, old data seems not to be removed (even if I clean all references of the fiddle from elements of the `ArrayCollection` or if `orphanRemoval` is set to true).

But let's enter a specific example. I have [this entity](https://github.com/ninsuo/twigfiddle/blob/master/web/src/Fuz/AppBundle/Entity/Fiddle.php) with lots of OneToOne / OneToMany relations to represent a [fiddle](http://twigfiddle.com). I can import fiddle samples (previously exported as json from another environment) using a Symfony2 command.

If the sample already exist, how can I update it properly?

#### The bad idea: doing DELETE + INSERT

I build my entity using the following code (reduced) :

```
$fiddle = new Fiddle();
$fiddle->setHash($this->get($json, 'hash'));
$fiddle->setRevision($this->get($json, 'revision'));

$context = $fiddle->getContext();
$context->setFormat($this->get($json, 'context', 'format'));
$context->setContent($this->get($json, 'context', 'content'));

$fiddle->clearTemplates();
$jsonTemplates = $this->get($json, 'templates') ? : array ();
foreach ($jsonTemplates as $jsonTemplate)
{
    $template = new FiddleTemplate();
    $template->setFilename($this->get($jsonTemplate, 'filename'));
    $template->setContent($this->get($jsonTemplate, 'content'));
    $template->setIsMain($this->get($jsonTemplate, 'is-main'));
    $fiddle->addTemplate($template);
}

// ...
```

I can now persist my entity after removing it if it already exists:

```
    $check = $this
       ->getContainer()
       ->get('doctrine')
       ->getRepository('FuzAppBundle:Fiddle')
       ->getFiddle($fiddle->getHash(), $fiddle->getRevision());

    if (!is_null($check->getId()))
    {
        $em->remove($check);
        $em->flush();
    }

    $em->persist($fiddle);
    $em->flush();
```

But this will create a DELETE + INSERT instead of an UPDATE if sample already exist. This is weird because users can bookmark fiddles and the relation is made by id.

#### The ugly idea: doing an UPDATE on main entity and OneToOne relations, and DELETE + INSERT on OneToMany relations

I get my fiddle first, and if it already exists, I clean it and fill it with the new data... **Code works well but is really ugly**, you can check it [here](https://github.com/ninsuo/twigfiddle/blob/master/web/src/Fuz/AppBundle/Command/ImportCommand.php).

As a sample, check out the `tags` property: as tags might have been removed / changed, I should properly set new tags, by replacing the older by the newer.

```
// remove the old tags
foreach ($fiddle->getTags() as $tag)
{
   if (\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork::STATE_MANAGED === $em->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityState($tag))
   {
      $em->remove($tag);
      $em->flush();
   }
}

// set the new tags
$tags = new ArrayCollection();
$jsonTags = $this->getFromArray($json, 'tags');
foreach ($jsonTags as $jsonTag)
{
   $tag = new FiddleTag();
   $tag->setTag($jsonTag);
   $tags->add($tag);
}
$fiddle->setTags($tags);
```

As tags are referenced using fiddle's id, I can use `->remove` even if that's ugly. This is OK here but if ids were autogenerated, there must be better solutions.

I also tried to simply set old fiddle's id to the new one and merge, but this leaded to the following exception:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]  
Notice: Undefined index: 00000000125168f2000000014b64e87f
```

## Bounty?

More than a simple "import feature", I want to use this update style to bind forms to non-managed entities and update existing entities only if required. So my goal is to make something generic applicable to all kind of entities.

But I of course don't expect the whole code. The good practice to deal with managed `ArrayCollection`'s updates, and some hints/warnings about what I should consider before coding this feature should be enough.

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to what's going on.  Why not just fetch your entity, make your updates, and then flush?  Why are you removing/persisting?

Comment: I can't make updates easily because there are lots of OneToOne / OneToMany : take the example of the `tags` property that contains an ArrayCollection: perhaps some tags were removed and some other added, and I need to use complex (and ugly) code to make the proper update. I used an update [here](https://github.com/ninsuo/twigfiddle/blob/master/web/src/Fuz/AppBundle/Command/ImportCommand.php) but as you can see, that's a huge code just for updating the object properly - I'm looking for something more automatic / simple, if Doctrine has it.

Comment: I just wish I better understood your specific issue, or what you're meaning by automatic flushing of the managed entity, etc.

Comment: When I bind a managed entity to a posted form (`$form->handleRequest($fiddle);`)` and the form is correctly fulfiled (`$form->isValid()` returns true), I need to do some other checks to see for example if the current user is able to save it. If he's granted to save, no problem; but if he's not granted to save, I should detach the entity to avoid it being automatically updated. I discovered this incredible automatic update just 3 days ago, and will never again use managed entities to handle forms until I fully understand what's going on.

Comment: Shouldn't you do that security check before the form ever checks if it is valid?  Like an `@Security` annotation to check?

Comment: They do not come to this route maliciously. If an user is not allowed to save a fiddle, fiddle is forked instead. The "Create new revision" button just calls the very same route as save (without rev number - but if a rev number is defined i should do a security check). Also, a fiddle can be owned by anonymous users (they can edit it until his session ends). Looks complex but in fact that's [just as simple as that](https://github.com/ninsuo/twigfiddle/blob/master/web/src/Fuz/AppBundle/Service/SaveFiddle.php#L59).

Comment: @JasonRoman I just found my issue. In fact my `flush()` isn't automatic, it is made by my anti-crawl security. So when flushing, all changes made on my entity are persisted. This confirms that I really need to process my forms on detached entities.

Comment: Oh that's very interesting, that's good information. Glad you figured it out

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Controlling what Doctrine persists

> Update existing entities only if required.

This can be achieved fairly simple with Doctrine:

What you're looking for is the Change Tracking Policy [Deferred Explicit](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html#deferred-explicit).

Doctrine will by default use the Change Tracking Policy [Deferred Implicit](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html#deferred-implicit). This means that when you call `$em->flush()`, Doctrine will go over *all* of its managed entities to calculate change-sets. Then all changes are persisted.

When using the Change Tracking Policy [Deferred Explicit](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html#deferred-explicit) and call `$em->flush()`, Doctrine will *only* go over the entities you've explicitly called `$em->persist()` on. In other words: You could have thousands of managed entities, called `$em->persist()` on 2 of them, and Doctrine will only calculate the change-sets of those 2 (and persist changes if needed).

The Change Tracking Policy can be set on an entity-class level. So if you want a certain entity class to use [Deferred Explicit](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html#deferred-explicit), simply add an annotation to the class doc-block:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @ChangeTrackingPolicy("DEFERRED_EXPLICIT")
 */
class Fiddle
{
```

Then it's just a matter of only calling `$em->persist($fiddle)` when you really need to.

It's probably wise to set the same Change Tracking Policy for an entire aggregate (the root entity and all of its children).

PS: There's also a third Change Tracking Policy named [Notify](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/change-tracking-policies.html#notify), which is a bit more work to set up, but gives you even more fine-grained control over what's persisted when calling `$em->flush()`. But I don't think you need to go this far.

### Updating the Fiddle

Seeing the code you use to update the Fiddle entity, I think you can improve some things there.

First move the responsibility of managing associations back to the entity:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @ChangeTrackingPolicy("DEFERRED_EXPLICIT")
 */
class Fiddle
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @return FiddleTag[]
     */
    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->tags->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * @param FiddleTag $tag
     */
    public function addTag(FiddleTag $tag)
    {
        if (!$this->tags->contains($tag)) {
            $this->tags->add($tag);
            $tag->setFiddle($this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param FiddleTag $tag
     */
    public function removeTag(FiddleTag $tag)
    {
        if ($this->tags->contains($tag)) {
            $this->tags->removeElement($tag);
            $tag->setFiddle(null);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param FiddleTag[] $newTags
     */
    public function replaceTags(array $newTags)
    {
        $currentTags = $this->getTags();

        // remove tags that are not in the new list of tags
        foreach ($currentTags as $currentTag) {
            if (!in_array($currentTag, $newTags, true)) {
                $this->removeTag($currentTag);
            }
        }

        // add tags that are not in the current list of tags
        foreach ($newTags as $newTag) {
            if (!in_array($newTag, $currentTags, true)) {
                $this->addTag($newTag);
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now the code in your ImportCommand can look something like this:

```
$jsonTags = $this->getFromArray($json, 'tags');
$newTags  = [];

foreach ($jsonTags as $jsonTag) {
    $tag = $tagRepo->findOneByTag($jsonTag);

    if ($tag === null) {
        $tag = new FiddleTag();
        $tag->setTag($jsonTag);
    }

    $newTags[] = $tag;
}

$fiddle->replaceTags($newTags);
```

Then when everything is ok and can be persisted, do:

```
$em->persist($fiddle);

foreach ($fiddle->getTags() as $tag) {
    $em->persist($tag);
}

$em->flush();
```

When you have configured `cascade=persist` on the association, you should be able to leave out the loop that manually persists the tags.

### Pro tip

You could have a look at the [JMS Serializer](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer) library, and the [Bundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle) that integrates it into Symfony.

Comment: This is a really interesting answer, thanks for sharing. I'll check that out within a couple of hours. Deferred implicit is the very reason why I've been so surprised about my unexpected persistence. Nice catch.